# Java List sort by one field and then by some specific value

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a list:

```
List<A> aList

where A:
public class A{
private Long id;

private LocalDate created;

private AStatus status; //enum

...other fields
}
```

```
public enum AStatus{
    NEW, SEND, WAITING, CANCELLED
}
```

How to sort my List FIRST by `created` in DESC order and then I want to have elements with the status `NEW` as first (and then elements with other `AStatus`), like:

```
1 10.12.2020 NEW
2 10.12.2020 SEND
3 10.12.2020 CANCELLED
4 08.12.2020 NEW
5 08.12.2020 NEW
```

Comment: IF we have eg. 3 rows with the same date then status NEW has to be always at the top of the list (as FIRST, before other AStatus for the same date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom `Comparator` that sorts with by `created` and then by a boolean of whether `status == AStatus.NEW` (remember - `false` comes before `true` when sorting booleans):

```
List<A> aList = // something...
    
// I assume these getters exist
aList.sort(Comparator.comparing(A::getCreated).reversed() 
                     .thenComparing(a -> a.getStatus() != AStatus.NEW)
);
```

Comment: one more thing - created has to be in DESC order... Ahhh... I have to use reverse() method probably

Comment: @Matley didn't notice that requirement, my bad. You can add a `reversed()` call there to reverse the order - see my edited answer

Comment: Another cool way to do it if this is the natural way these objects of type A will be compared is to add the Comparable interface to your class and keep the logic inside the class instead of outside. Then you will just use list.sort();